# How to stop object after fixed distance/time when using applyImpulse (Swift, iOS)?

Tags: ios, iphone, ipad, swift

In Swift, is it possible to get an object to stop moving after a fixed distance/time when using `applyImpulse` on an object? One option is to use `SKAction.runSequence` and do something like this:

```
applyImpulse
waitForDuration
object.physicsBody?.velocity = CGVectorMake(0, 0)
```

This seems clunky, however.

The other option is to move the object manually through the position property, but this causes us to lose the built-in physics effects, which we hope to retain.